# Permuting digits in a power of $2$

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, decimal-expansion

Does there exist a natural number $N$ that is a power of $2$ whose digits (in the decimal representation) can be permuted to a *different* power of $2$?

*Thoughts*:

If such a number $N$ exists, then after permutation a new number $N'$ is obtained. Let us assume, without loss of generality, that $N\lt N'$.

Now since, N' and N have the same number of digits, then $N'$ must be either equal to $2N$, $4N$, or $8N$, because on multiplying $16$ clearly the number of digits increases.

Therefore $N'-N$ must be of the form $N,3N,7N$

This doesn't seem to lead anywhere though.

Comment: *Hint* take modulo $9$, then the sum of digit of the number for both the powers of $2$ are same !

Comment: @r9m answer pointed that out very craftily. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** So we have a number $2^a$. When we permute the digits, we get say $2^b$. Note however that if we take a number $N$ and permute its digits to get $N'$, then $9$ must divide $N-N'$.

**Remark:** This only deals with the problem if we do not allow initial $0$'s.